# Import AppInsight Instrumentation Key through Release/CD and Update Instrumentation key in appsettings of an Application

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have two CD/Release Definition; one is ARM for Application Insight and another CD is for deploying the App.

- First one is creating Application Insight in Azure.
- Second CD is used to deploy the App.[*App is not a WebApp; it's API deploying in SF Cluster*]

Planning to merge the two CD/Release definition and create a One CD/Release Definition.
once Application Insight created then get the Instrumentation key and update the instrumentation key in appsettings of App.
Found one solution from Github; which will through "output" tag in ARM and  PowerShell script to get the instrumentation key once deployment finished. But it's failing -
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-templates-outputs.md#define-and-use-output-values

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
At D:\a\_temp\ded99e61-d7aa-40d7-979a-dfff517ed558.ps1:7 char:1
+ Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment "XXXXXX"  "XXXXXXXXX"
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzur 
eResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

- Code wise I have two solution one is ARM for App Insight and another one is SF Cluster App Solution. I can not pull all the ARM and merged it in the App solution.

My tasks are -
[image]

CD is failing in "PowerShell Script" task.

Please provide the best possible ways to do this.

Comment: Are you using the Azure Resource Group Deployment task? Or the Azure PowerShell task? Both of those handle logging in to Azure properly for you.

Comment: Using Azure Group Deployment task

Comment: Where and how are you running the command that's failing? `Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`?

Comment: CD is failing in "Powershell task", uploaded the image in post

Comment: Use an Azure PowerShell task instead.

Comment: Powershell script is - (Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name> -Name <deployment-name>).Outputs.resourceID.value

Comment: will try Azure PowerShell task; thanks a lot

Comment: Excellent!  Azure PowerShell task is working, one more help where do I get Deployment deployment-name. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running a script that interacts with Azure, use the `Azure PowerShell` task.

Specify a variable for the `Deployment Outputs` parameter in the [`Azure Resource Group Deployment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=vsts) task, and you'll get a variable populated with the outputs (which, IIRC, should contain the deployment name). It's a JSON object, so you can parse it with `ConvertFrom-JSON`.

If you specify a variable named `Foo`, you can access it in a down-stream script as `$env:Foo`.